# Printing Console Output Messages Using Redshift Connector

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I normally use JetBrains IDE DataGrip to connect to my Redshift cluster. When I run the following command:

```
select 1 as n;
```

In the Output box of DataGrip, I get the following messages:

> [2024-03-11 12:24:59] 1 row retrieved starting from 1 in 157 ms (execution: 57 ms, fetching: 100 ms)

However, when I connect to Redshift via `redshift_connector` using Python in a Jupyter Notebook and run the following command:

```
cursor.execute('select 1 as n;')
```

I don't see that message. Is there anyway to return that status message from Python?